# Create a data patch to update telephone field saved in the table company Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, backend, magento2.3.1, magento2.3.2

In Company & company_address table , data across the telephone field is saved as (234)-378-4949. I want to refine the old data using data patch so that it will saved in numbers only i.e. 2343784949

Can someone suggest how can i create a data patch which will run on deploy to automatically refine all enteries across 'telephone' field of the company and company_address table

Answer (score 0):

You can use below type of Recurring.php and it will run in every upgrade.

Path: Setup/Recurring.php

```
<?php
namespace Mypackage\Test\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;
class Recurring implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime
 */
protected $dateTime;

public function __construct(
    DateTime $dateTime
) {
    $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
}

public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();
    $setup->getConnection()->query("INSERT INTO mypackage_tabel SET log_datetime = '" . $this->datetime->gmtTimestamp() . "'"); // Add query or logic which refine your entry.
    $setup->endSetup();
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Saurabh, Thanks for the guide but I want to create a data patch only. Can you guide me how to achieve this using data patch?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : You need to create a custom validation rule by creating custom module

app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

Step 2 : Add custom validation js file. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/web/js/validator-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'moment'
], function ($, moment) {
    'use strict';

    return function (validator) {

        validator.addRule(
            'custom-validate-telephone',
            function (value, params) {                
                 var phoneno = /^[-+]?[0-9]+$/;

                if((value.match(phoneno))){
                    return true;
                }       
            },
            $.mage.__("Please enter phone number(only numbers).")
        );

        return validator;
    };
});
```

Step 3 : app/code/VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/di.xml

Step 4 : Apply this custom rule for shipping and billing form LayoutProcessor.php

Hope this could be helpful for you.

Thank You

Comment: Hi Oscprofessionals- Thanks for the guide but I want to create a data patch only which will format telephone number from Company table